# Expanding divs via jquery requiring extra clicks to activate

Tags: jquery, html, css

Okay - I'm not a big jQuery user - so this is probably a fairly simple-to-solve question, but as I am uncertain what is causing this difficulty, I have had a great deal of trouble finding anything about it.

THE PROBLEM: I have a series of divs on a page, one above another. Each of them is to perform the same function of expanding when clicked on, then contracting once clicked on again. Originally, I had planned on using a single jquery script for all 3, but I could not figure out how to apply it without all 3 divs opening simultaneously. I moved on to using 3 of the same script, each referring to a specific div, which also made it simple to have them scale to the right height. However, with my current code, once I click on any one of the 3 divs, it takes 2 clicks instead of one to make the next one perform its transition. How does one get around this?

THE CODE:

```
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
isLarge = false; 
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".dropdown_1").click(function(){
$(".dropdown_1").animate({height:(isLarge ? '33px' : '100px')});
isLarge = !isLarge;    
});
}); 

isLarge = false; 
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".dropdown_2").click(function(){
$(".dropdown_2").animate({height:(isLarge ? '33px' : '100px')});
isLarge = !isLarge;    
});
}); 

isLarge = false; 
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".dropdown_3").click(function(){
$(".dropdown_3").animate({height:(isLarge ? '33px' : '100px')});
isLarge = !isLarge;    
});
}); 
</script>
<style>
h4 {
width: 745px;
height: 26px;
display: inline-block;
border-bottom: 4px solid #740000;
padding-bottom: 3px;
padding-left: 5px;
font-size: 24px;
-webkit-text-shadow: 0px 1px 5px black;
-moz-text-shadow: 0px 1px 5px black;
text-shadow: 0px 1px 5px black;
margin: 0 0 5px 0;
}

h5 {
margin: 10px 0 10px 8px;
font-size: 18px;
-webkit-text-shadow: 0px 1px 5px black;
-moz-text-shadow: 0px 1px 5px black;
text-shadow: 0px 1px 5px black
}
    div.dropdown_1 {
-moz-transition: height 2s;
-ms-transition: height 2s;
-o-transition: height 2s;
-webkit-transition: height 2s;
background: #c06d00; 
height: 33px;
width: 750px;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
margin: 0 0 35px 25px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px 1px black;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px 1px black;
box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px 1px black;
background-image: url(images/dropdown_arrow.png);
background-position: right top;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

div.dropdown_2 {
-moz-transition: height 2s;
-ms-transition: height 2s;
-o-transition: height 2s;
-webkit-transition: height 2s;
background: #c06d00; 
height: 33px;
width: 750px;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
margin: 0 0 35px 25px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px 1px black;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px 1px black;
box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px 1px black;
background-image: url(images/dropdown_arrow.png);
background-position: right top;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

div.dropdown_3 {
-moz-transition: height 2s;
-ms-transition: height 2s;
-o-transition: height 2s;
-webkit-transition: height 2s;
background: #c06d00; 
height: 33px;
width: 750px;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
margin: 0 0 35px 25px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px 1px black;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px 1px black;
box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px 1px black;
background-image: url(images/dropdown_arrow.png);
background-position: right top;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="content">
    <a href="index.html">
    <div id="header_img_bwf">
    </div>
    </a>
    <div id="body">
        <h3>Programs</h3>
        <div class="dropdown_1">
            <h4>title</h4>
            <h5>title</h5>
            <p>text</p>
            <p>text</p>  
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown_2">
            <h4>title</h4>
            <h5>title</h5>
            <p>text</p>
            <p>text</p>                 
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown_3">
            <h4>title</h4>
            <h5>title</h5>
            <p>text</p>
            <p>text</p> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I would be so grateful if someone could point me in the right direction on this one, thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle or codepen for your code ?

Answer (score 1):

Rename your `dropdown_1`, `dropdown_2`, `dropdown_3` to `dropdown` and then use following code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".dropdown").click(function () {
        var height = '33px';
        if ($(this).hasClass("open")) {
            height = '33px';
            $(this).removeClass("open");
        } else {
            height = '100px';
            $(this).addClass("open")
        }
        $(this).animate({
            height: height
        });
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Xxuzt/

Answer (score 0):

Your `isLarge` variable is common to the 3 divs. You should name it individually (`isLarge1`, `isLarge2`, `isLarge3`).

Answer (score 0):

```
            <HTML>
            <head>
            <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
            </script>
            <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                initAccordian();
            });

            function initAccordian(){
                $("div.dropdown").click(function(){
                    collapsAllOtherDivs();
                    //--here $(this) refer to currently clicked Div.
                    if($(this).height()==33){
                        $(this).animate({height:('100px')});
                    }else{
                        $(this).animate({height:('33px')});
                    }
                });
            }

            function collapsAllOtherDivs(){
                $("div.dropdown").animate({height:('33px')});
            }
            </script>

            <style>
            h4 {
                width: 745px;
                height: 26px;
                display: inline-block;
                border-bottom: 4px solid #740000;
                padding-bottom: 3px;
                padding-left: 5px;
                font-size: 24px;
                -webkit-text-shadow: 0px 1px 5px black;
                -moz-text-shadow: 0px 1px 5px black;
                text-shadow: 0px 1px 5px black;
                margin: 0 0 5px 0;
            }

            h5 {
                margin: 10px 0 10px 8px;
                font-size: 18px;
                -webkit-text-shadow: 0px 1px 5px black;
                -moz-text-shadow: 0px 1px 5px black;
                text-shadow: 0px 1px 5px black
            }

            div.dropdown {
            -moz-transition: height 2s;
            -ms-transition: height 2s;
            -o-transition: height 2s;
            -webkit-transition: height 2s;
            background: #c06d00;
                height: 33px;
                width: 750px;
                position: relative;
                overflow: hidden;
                margin: 0 0 35px 25px;
                -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px 1px black;
                -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px 1px black;
                box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px 1px black;
                background-image: url(images/dropdown_arrow.png);
                background-position: right top;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
            }
            </style>

            </head>
                <body>
                <div id="content">
                    <a href="index.html">
                    <div id="header_img_bwf">
                    </div>
                    </a>
                    <div id="body">
                        <h3>Programs</h3>
                        <div class="dropdown">
                            <h4>title</h4>
                            <h5>title</h5>
                            <p>text</p>
                            <p>text</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="dropdown">
                            <h4>title</h4>
                            <h5>title</h5>
                            <p>text</p>
                            <p>text</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="dropdown">
                            <h4>title</h4>
                            <h5>title</h5>
                            <p>text</p>
                            <p>text</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </body>
            </HTML>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9V4MJ/